# How to allow optional e-type arguments in the middle?

Tags: xparse, optional-arguments

For example, if I want to define a command produces functions with given name, I use the following code:

```
\NewDocumentCommand \fun { m e{\sp\sb} O{} } 
  { 
    \operatorname{\mathrm{#1}}
    \IfNoValueTF{#2}{}{\sp#2}
    \IfNoValueTF{#3}{}{\sb#3}
    \ifblank{#4}{}
      {\left(#4\right)} 
  }
```

or the following one:

```
\NewDocumentCommand \fun { m e{^_} O{} } 
  { 
    \operatorname{\mathrm{#1}}
    \IfNoValueTF{#2}{}{\sp#2}
    \IfNoValueTF{#3}{}{\sb#3}
    \ifblank{#4}{}
      {\left(#4\right)} 
  }
```

However, they have problems: the first one only accepts one character as the argument `#2` and `#3`, 
while the latter makes all following characters (including those that should be viewed as argument `#4`) as 
the argument `#2` or `#3`.

**How to fix this?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to enclose the arguments in braces, otherwise TeX will only use the first one in the sub/superscript. Also, `\IfValueT{#2}{\sp{#2}}` is easier than `\IfNoValueTF{#2}{}{\sp{#2}}`, and I also defined a `\IfBlankTF` using `expl3`:

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{xparse}
\ExplSyntaxOn
\cs_new_eq:NN \IfBlankTF \tl_if_blank:nTF
\ExplSyntaxOff
\NewDocumentCommand \fun { m e{^_} O{} }
  {%
    \operatorname{#1}%
    \IfValueT{#2}{\sp{#2}}%
    \IfValueT{#3}{\sb{#3}}%
    \IfBlankTF{#4}{}
      {\left(#4\right)}%
  }
\begin{document}
\(\fun{blub}_{foo}^{bar}[zzz]\)
\end{document}
```

> [image]

Also, with the next `xparse` update (TL'20), when you define a token as delimiter, like in:

```latex
\NewDocumentCommand \fun { e{\sp\sb} } { ... }
```

then the `e` argument will only match if you have the literal tokens `\sp` and `\sb` in the document (that is, `\fun\sp{arg1}\sb{arg2}`), but not if you have some token with the same meaning, like `\fun^{arg1}_{arg2}`. Same thing if you define:

```latex
\NewDocumentCommand \fun { e{^_} } { ... }
```

then the function will match `\fun^{arg1}_{arg2}` but *not* `\fun\sp{arg1}\sb{arg2}`.